# How to use facebook's Webhooks for non admin pages?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-page, webhooks, facebook-permissions

Am trying to use Facebook's Webhooks for pages to get feeds and ratings notification. Am able to get notification if I'm the admin of the page but am not able to get any notification for the pages I'm not an admin, even though I hold the page access token which is been granted by the admin of the page to my App.

I tried calling

`https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/<page-id>/subscribed_apps?access_token=<page-token>`

but got

```
{"error":{"message":"(#200) User does not have sufficient administrative permission for this action on this page.","type":"OAuthException","code":200,"fbtrace_id":"BzRm1gqdTBH"}}
```

In Facebook documentation, its mentioned  "page-related RTU objects will require that your app be installed on the page". Have installed my App in the respective page as page tab. Still its the same.